# The second time onChange is triggered, custom component does not update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, onchange, custom-component

**Question:** When `props.files` is console logged (look at code below to see where it's logged), it works the first time. But, when I select a new set of files, it never console logs anything again, unless I reload the page and start over. What am I doing wrong here?

**Info on my code:**

I am using [React Bootstrap Form Components](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#forms-file) (scroll to "File Input") for the following custom component (i.e. Form.Group, Form.Label, Form.Control). Code is heavily simplified for clarity:

```
const UploadFile = (props) => {
  // stuff here

  console.log(props.files);

  const filesFunction = (filesInput) {
     // do stuff with filesInput
  }
  
  return {
     <Form.Group controlId="formFileMultiple" className="mb-3">
        <Form.Label> Files </Form.Label>
        <Form.Control 
           type="file" multiple 
           onChange={props.handleFilesChange}
           onChange={filesFunction(files)}
           name="files"
           key="files"
        />
     </Form.Group>
  }
```

In the parent, I have an instance of the custom UploadFile component, as such:

```
const [listOfFiles, setListOfFiles] = useState([]);

const handleFilesChange = (e) {
   setListOfFiles(e.target.files);
}

<UploadFile 
   handleFilesChange = { e => handleFilesChange(e) }
   files = {listOfFiles}
/>
```

Comment: if `handleFilesChange` isn't working, you should include that code in the question. you've shown us pretty much everything except what's actually relevant to the problem.

Comment: `handleFilesChange` is in the code but only in the parent! That might be the reason it is not working

Comment: @thomas, I included it in the onChange. Does it not get triggered that way?

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. That is all I have for handleFilesChanges. What else would you like to see?

Comment: @penguin it should be triggered, I don't see why it shouldn't... what happens when you put a console log inside the `handleFilesChange` function? Does it show everytime you upload new files?

Comment: @thomas When I console log inside of handleFilesChange in the parent, it works perfectly every time. However, for the console log inside of the UploadFile component, it only console logs once. After I reselect files, nothing it outputted.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "it never works again?"

Comment: I think that is because your render method does not use the `props.files` anywhere. Try replacing `<Form.Label>` with `<Form.Label className={\`random-calss-depending-on-nbr-of-files-${props.files.length}\`}>`

Comment: @Alan. Yes! I clarified it in the post now.

Comment: Okay, my hunch is that React doesn't detect this as a change `setListOfFiles(e.target.files);`  You could instead try `setListOfFiles([...e.target.files]);` or `const files = e.target.files; setListOfFiles([...files]);`

Comment: @Alan, this worked! However, the problem is that, ListOfFiles needs to remain of type FileList and not be converted to an array.

Comment: @penguin Okay, if that's the case, for your state, you can use an object with a property called files. `const [listOfFiles, setListOfFiles] = useState({files: {});` Then in your onChange method create a new object. `const files = e.target.files; setListOfFiles(f=>({...f,files});`

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: If you want to `console.log` to be triggered in the UploadFile component, you have to trigger a rerender. Currently I don't see you using `props.files` inside the render method of the UploadFile component. Maybe try this:

```
const UploadFile = (props) => {
  // stuff here

  console.log(props.files);
  const randomClassName = `random-class-name-${props.files.length}`;

  return {
     <Form.Group controlId="formFileMultiple" className="mb-3">
        <Form.Label className={randomClassName}> Files </Form.Label>
        <Form.Control 
           type="file" multiple 
           onChange={props.handleFilesChange}
           name="files"
           key="files"
        />
     </Form.Group>
  }
}
```

But the proper way of doing this would be using the `useEffect` hook, which gets triggered every time your variable changes independently of the render method. Here's an example:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

const UploadFile = (props) => {
  
  useEffect(() => {
    // stuff here
    console.log(props.files);
  }, [props.files]);
  
  return {
     <Form.Group controlId="formFileMultiple" className="mb-3">
        <Form.Label> Files </Form.Label>
        <Form.Control 
           type="file" multiple 
           onChange={props.handleFilesChange}
           name="files"
           key="files"
        />
     </Form.Group>
  }
}
```

Comment: Just tried this. Unfortunately, it does not work. Got the same result as before.

Comment: updated the answer, not sure if it will help you but you can try this out ^^

Comment: Hi @thomas. I haven't heard of useEffects, so I will be doing more research on that. Thanks for that! But, I tried what you've written, and I'm still getting the origin result again :(

Answer (score 0):

React doesn't know how to manage the `FileList` and doesn't see these props changes in the child component. If you convert `FileList` to `array` it works perfectly.

```js
const UploadFile = (props) => {
  // stuff here

  console.log(props.files);
  
  return <ReactBootstrap.Form.Group controlId="formFileMultiple" className="mb-3">
      <ReactBootstrap.Form.Label> Files </ReactBootstrap.Form.Label>
      <ReactBootstrap.Form.Control 
         type="file" multiple 
         onChange={props.handleFilesChange}
         name="files"
         key="files"
      />
   </ReactBootstrap.Form.Group>
}

function App() {
  const [listOfFiles, setListOfFiles] = React.useState([]);

  const handleFilesChange = (e) => {
     setListOfFiles(Array.from(e.target.files));
  }

  return <UploadFile 
     handleFilesChange = { e => handleFilesChange(e) }
     files = {listOfFiles}
  />
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />, 
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>

<script
  src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"
  crossorigin></script>

<script
  src="https://unpkg.com/react-bootstrap@next/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js"
  crossorigin></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

**Clarification:**

The FileList is unmanaged by react, because its value can only be set by a user and not programmatically: https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#the-file-input-tag

Comment: Thank you. However, I need to keep the type as FileList because it's required for the service that "files" will go into as an input. It seems that there is no way that array can be converted back to FileList, or is there?

Comment: No @penguin. You will need save the `FileList` and the `array` as props.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It turns out the service uses both types (FileList and array) and it works perfectly, so no need for two props. I also had another quick question - if I wanted to use "files" as an input for a function in UploadFile, after the user selects files, how would I do this? I've updated the code above to include the function (filesFunction) and the onChange (added a second onChange), but this doesn't work, as we can't have two onChanges at once.

Comment: if I understand correctly: `onChange={(e) => {props.handleFilesChange(e); otherFunction(e.target.files) }}` or better in `handleFilesChange`